# Store img src(encrypt image) to javascript array, and upload it.

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have some problem, i want to upload multiple image using Ajax,but before upload it, i want to store it to javascript array first. how i can do this thing,
my script :

```
<img id="prepareupload" width="200" hidden="" height="200" alt="your image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4R/YRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAEQEOAAIAAAAgAAAI5gEPAAIAAAAgAAAJBgEQAAIAAAAgAAAJJgESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAJRgEbAAUAAAABAAAJTgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAuAAAJVgEyAAIAAAAUAAAJhAITAAMAAAABAAIAAAIgAAQAAAABAAAAAAIhAAQAAAABAAAAAAIiAAQAAAABAAAAAAIjAAQAAAABAAAAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAJmIglAAQAAAABAAATMOocAAcAAAgMAAAA2gAAFEwc6gAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...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" style="border: 1px solid black; display: inline;">
```

nah, how to store it to JS array and how to upload this image,
thank you..

Comment: Can I ask why you want to put it into an array first?

Comment: becouse i want to upload multiple image, btw <img id="prepareupload" > is  a container (image preview) for <input type='file>,

Comment: Then, [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) is a good option. Get the blob data from `input` element rather than `img`. See the below solution.

Comment: yeah, it works, thnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do that with an array. You should use FormData.

```
var formData = new FormData();
//Supposing you are getting them from an input file
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Then something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url here',
    data: formData,
    // Must have this
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
})
```

Comment: @VinraGunantaPandia make sure to mark this as the correct answer then. ;)

Comment: sorry @K 0, i forget it, i just vote up, but forget to mark this as the correct answer, forgive me :P,,
anyway.. thanks man..